# Access to a JSON Value in Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, api, angular7

Hello I'm trying to access to an especific key from a JSON. I'm using node.js and angular 7
The JSON I got is stringfy and it comes from an API.

This is the JSON I got

```
  "search": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "dn": "uid=080030781,c=mx,ou=s,o=i.com",
        "attribute": [
          { "name": "mail", "value": ["CAMILA.CAMPOS.TELLEZ@mail.com", "MX08@mail.com"] }]
      }
    ],
      "return": {
      "code": 0,
        "message": "Success",
          "count": 1
    }
  }
}
```

I need to access to the key "value", because I need to get the value "camila.campos.tellez@mail.com".
I get the JSON from an API declarated in a node.js file called app.js, then I catch the response from it using this service.ts file

```
 getApproverMail(name) {
    console.log('entered to rootservice');
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/costing/operations?name=' + name);
  }
```

Finally I can access to this through a component.ts fil with this code

```
findApproverMail() {

    this.rootService.getApproverMail(this.aproverName).subscribe((res) => {
      this.email = res;
      console.log('Test: ' + res);
    });

  }
```

And the browser console prints the JSON I have show you. But how can I access only to the mail's value? 
P.D I need only the mail because after I got it the web site needs to send an email to that direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation. Any valid JSON is an object in JavaScript (and TypeScript). You can use dot notation to navigate into the object:

```js
findApproverMail() {

    this.rootService.getApproverMail(this.aproverName).subscribe((res) => {
      this.email = res.search.entry[0].attribute[0].value[0];
      console.log('Test: ' + res);
    });

  }
```

I would recommend defining an `interface` in the shape of what you expect from the service. It's cleaner than just indexing around an `any` typed object.

Also note that I hard code `0` indexes because that answers your question. You might consider a more dynamic / flexible way to get the address or elements you need.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me and I got this error :(
"res.search.entry is undefined"

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, I realized I wasn't sending the Json Object, I only send a string with the Json data, that's why I couldn't access to the object in the way you told me. Thank you!

Comment: For that you can use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`